# i want to pass php variable through the dynamic href link image to another php page

Tags: php

here i want to pass a dynamic variable '$cost' to another php page 'onewaytrip_passanger_data.php', through dynamically generated href link image. The code for href link image write into php tag
This is my code. but it is not working..

```
<?php
    $cost=$row['fare'];
    echo '<a href="onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?fare="$cost""><img src="images/bookbutton.png" width="85" height="20" /></a>';
?>
```

Comment: Please check your quotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
echo '<a href="onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?fare=$cost""><img src="images/bookbutton.png" width="85" height="20" /></a>';
```

to

```
echo '<a href="onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?fare='.$cost.'"><img src="images/bookbutton.png" width="85" height="20" /></a>';
```

Comment: @AnilkumarMT For clarity. When using single quotes, PHP will not replace the variable name with it's value in the string.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```
echo '<a href="onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?fare='.$cost.'"><img src="images/bookbutton.png" width="85" height="20" /></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Always keep yourself confuse free. What is the need to do echo anchor tag. When, it can be done like this way.
Now, try.

```
<?php $cost=$row['fare'];?>
    <a href="onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?fare=<?echo $cost;">
       <img src="images/bookbutton.png" width="85" height="20" />
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=\"onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?fare=\"$cost\"><img src=\"images/bookbutton.png\" width="85" height="20" /></a>";
```

or

```
 echo "<a href=\"onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?fare=\"" . $cost . "\"><img src=\"images/bookbutton.png\" width="85" height="20" /></a>";
```